# Kubernetes Cronjobs are not removed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm running the following cronjob in my minikube:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  suspend: false
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - somefailure
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I've added the "somefailure" to force failing of the job. My problem is that it seems that my minikube installation (running v1.23.3) ignores `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `failedJobsHistoryLimit`. I've checked the documentation on https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/ and it says that both parameters are available, but in the end, Kubernetes generates up to 10 jobs. When I add `ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 1`, it removes the container after 1 second, but the other parameters are completely ignored.
So I wonder if I need to enable something in minikube or if these parameters are deprecated or what's the reason why it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's a Kubernetes bug: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53331.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Steve I disagree in this instance; even if you remove the link, "It seems like it's a Kubernetes bug" *is*, in fact, an answer to the question. I don't know enough about the topic to know whether it's a *correct* answer, but it does appear to be an answer.